# Working with CGM version 4 files?

Tags: converters, file-format, cgm

My local government requires the use of [ActiveCGM](http://www.mern.gouv.qc.ca/english/land/register/register-tools-cgm.jsp) (which I believe is a form of CGM file format, version 4) for viewing technical documents.

The standard is [well-documented](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Computer_Graphics_Metafile&oldid=640192792#Standards) but the idea of reading and implementing a 449 page specification sounds like a non-starter to me. Unfortunately, I can't find any decent tool for converting CGM v4 to a modern file format.

I don't mind losing active elements (such as hover) in the conversion process but I need to retain static elements (such as vectors and text) because I need to parse measurements embedded in the document.

How do I access CGM v4 in a programmatic manner, or convert it to a more recent file format?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jcgm frame with Apache FOP. 
With a little bit xsl and java coding effort,
you can convert XML+CGM documents to PDF files

jcgm can convert CGM files to standart graphic formats like
jpg, png, etc.

There are some samples in jcgm documentation...
Jcgm is an Apache project and It is 90% accurate..

Bkapan...